# What does the phrase "emerging from the haze" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Could you help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "emerging from the haze" here?

> It's important to keep this app within reach, whether you're emerging
> from the haze of night feeds with your baby or dealing with their
> bedtimes.

Comment: Remember to link to the source

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a new baby that required regular feeding during the night?  The parents have to wake up every couple of hours during the night.  It makes them tired during the day, and feel "hazy"

When the baby starts to sleep for longer and doesn't require such regular feeding, they can start to feel more clear headed - hence figuratively "emerge from the haze"  (an expression which can also be used literally, when a person approaches on a foggy day)